# Connect to Ubuntu Linux VPN

Tags: linux, vpn

How can I connect my Android devices (2.3.3 and 4.0) to VPN setup in Ubuntu Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look under Settings > Wireless & Networks. You should see a VPN option. Assuming you already have a VPN server running on your Ubuntu machine, it should be pretty self-explanatory from there